# Authenticate automatically against box.com to get api access

Tags: python, box-api

Box.com supports different authentication method, OAuth2 and JWT. I'm currently using OAuth2 with develop tokens, which works just fine. The developer tokens expires within an hour so I can't use this in our production.

I'm using the [python SDK](https://github.com/box/box-python-sdk) to upload files to box, and there is no user interaction here at all. It seems like I can't use the OAuth2 authentication method since there is no users uploading (automatic script), am I right?

The JWT authentication method requires an enterprise id, which I can't find. I used this page as reference: https://box-content.readme.io/docs/box-platform

I've logged in as an co-admin in box, but can't find the enterprise id or Custom apps under the APPS menu.

Is there anything I have missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use JWT to make server to server api call. you can find your enterprise ID in you Admin Console-->Enterprise Setting--> Account Info-->Enterprise ID.

Comment: One more thing, you also need make sure in your Application, OAuth2 Parameters-->Manage enterprise and Manage users  is checked. otherwise, you will get an error: Bearer realm="Service", error="insufficient_scope", error_description="The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token."

Comment: Thanks for your input. Co-Admins can't see the Enterprise settings or Account Info. Maybe it's only the Admin who can setup all of this...

Comment: I can confirm that only true admins can see these settings... box.com... is it possible,,,